# How to resolve AttributeError while calling API?

Tags: python, api

I am facing error in Python when trying to call information through API of a Share Brokerage site

```
AttributeError: module 'websocket' has no attribute 'WebSocketApp'
```

I am getting this error when I am trying to connect to websocket to get live updates. The same piece of code was working earlier but not working now.

Snapshot of the error
[image]

Below is the piece of code where I am getting the error.

```
enter code here

from time import sleep
from alice_blue import *
import json
from Login import *


 access_token=open('C:/Users/Anuj Sinha/OneDrive/WD/OneDrive/Automated 
 Share Trading App/API Integration/access_token.txt','r').read().strip()

alice = AliceBlue(username,password,access_token)

socket_opened = False
def event_handler_quote_update(message):
   print(f"quote update {message}")

def open_callback():
  global socket_opened
  socket_opened = True

alice.start_websocket(subscribe_callback=event_handler_quote_update,
                  socket_open_callback=open_callback,
                  run_in_background=True)
while(socket_opened==False):
   pass
alice.subscribe(alice.get_instrument_by_symbol('NSE', 'ONGC'), 
  LiveFeedType.MARKET_DATA)
  sleep(10)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7vN7.png)

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: always put code, data and error message as text, not image.

Comment: maybe you created file `websocket.py` or folder `websocket` and now it imports your file instead expected module - and it can't find `WebSocketApp` in your file.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please read, [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to find out how to get the best answers to your questions.

Comment: Your code please? E.g. via a public git repo?

Comment: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @AnujSinha please edit your question and add the code. It's not generally a good idea to paste large amounts of code in a comment because it's hard to read. We aren't trying to be mean, we are just trying to help.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Thanks for the suggetion. I have removed the code from the comment and added in the post. Will you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: @AnujSinha is this Alice Blue code from the API? or is it something you custom wrote? It looks like that file is yours but that's where you tie in the API. I don't know how you're importing the API inside of there. Also can you give me a link to the API's documentation? In either case, it looks like the code you've already posted is breaking before it does anything.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Yes ths is code from Aliceblue API.I didn't wrote any custom code and this was working earlier but suddenly stopped working from past few days.Its breaking at a point where its trying to call Websocket.

Comment: @AnujSinha In your python console can you run `pip show websocket-client` for me and show me what you get? If that errors out can you run `pip show websockets`?

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim I have added the CMD snapshot.Please let me know what I need to do to resolve my issue.

Comment: @AnujSinha just to be clear, you're not using a virtual environment for your code? Because the screenshot you listed is done in a base environment and not in a virtual environment. Sorry for me asking so many questions. I'm trying to narrow your problem down.

Comment: @Rashid'Lee'Ibrahim Its completely fine in asking questions.I am happy to answer. No I am not using virtual environment.I took help from this link..https://github.com/krishnavelu/alice_blue .

Answer (score 0):

Not positive this will fix your problem, but the steps are too long for a comment.

There are a couple things to try at this point.

First we want to make sure the package `websockets` is NOT installed.

```
pip uninstall websocket
```

Then we also want to uninstall `websocket-client` and install from source.

So in your terminal, run the commands.

```
pip uninstall websocket-client

pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade websocket-client
```

Now check and see if the program runs properly. If it works, congradulations you are done. If it doesn't work, try a full reinstall from source of alice blue.

```
pip uninstall alice_blue

pip --no-cache-dir install --upgrade alice_blue
```

**Separately from your original problem**

I also noticed that you are reading your access token from a txt file. According to their documentation you need to generate one by accessing an endpoint of theirs.
That's probably because the access tokens are short lived and will time out.

```
access_token = AliceBlue.login_and_get_access_token(username='username', password='password', twoFA='a',  api_secret='api_secret')
```

If all of this still doesn't help, I can keep looking to see if I can find anything else.

Comment: Thanks a lot my problem got fixed.